# why assign a name/id to a <select> in a drop down list

Tags: html

I'm looking at some code my teacher wrote, here is the code snippet for an HTML drop down list:

```
<form name="year" id="year">
<select name="year" id="year">      <!--What is the purpose of naming select?-->
<option>Freshman</option>
<option>Sophomore</option>
<option>Junior</option>
<option>Senior</option>
<option>Grad Student</option>
</select>
</form>
```

What is the purpose of naming the select statement? What could this be used for later in the code?
Thank you

Comment: Because the value(s) from `option` will be passed for that name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most basic explanation: `name` attribute is used when submitting the form and retrieving on the server-side. The `id` attribute is used for JavaScript functions, such as a `change` event.

Comment: The `id` attribute can also be used for CSS style selectors -- although there are duplicate `id`s in this markup, which is invalid.